# data structures in assembly language

Tags: assembly

recently i've downloaded a guide of the assembly language, that teach you reversing and something other, from the site [Crackmes](http://crackmes.de)

i'm doing the "lessons" but i can't understand how data structures work.
so for exemple:
1) what's the instruction: mov large fs:0, eax
2) what's the SEH and why it's used to create a data structure
3) how is the input stored in the data structure?

can you explain me what does it occur, please?

thanks all

Comment: There are good assembly language tutorials all over the Web. Why would you go to a reverse engineering site for basic assembly language info? Assembly language programming isn't something you can learn overnight by going through a few lessons. You should get a good tutorial that starts with the basics. One good example is http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html. Or search for "x86 assembly language tutorial."

Comment: thanks for the answer but i already knew something about the assembly language( from other more complete guides ). i wanted to know something more about reversing( lawful purposes ). thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SEH" == Structured Exception Handler.   This is a Microsoft Windows feature to support programs (including assembler programs) pass exceptions in a standard way.  The

```
mov   fs:0, eax
```

if I recall correctly, is about setting up the Structured Exception Handler. If you want
to know more about this, go to Microsoft's MSDN site and learn about it.

While useful, none of the SEH stuff is really about data structures.

If you want to learn about data structures in general, "reversing" (reverse engineering) isn't the way to do it.   If that's not what you mean, you'll only get confusing answers to your somewhat confusing question.

In particular, I wouldn't spend a lot of energy trying to learn from a site that appears to be dedicated to cracking code.

Comment: thanks for the answer i'd like having the answer to the third question, please. i imagine through the stack.. thanks again

Comment: If you want to understand how SEH works, read the MS documentation on SEH.    Its rather long and seemingly complext; better you should read the original that I try to guess what you don't understand about it.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx